# sIFR 3 text won't show in a subfolder

Tags: text, sifr, subdirectory

I am using sIFR3 and I have not placed any restrictions i.e. sIFR.domains = ['*']. sIFR text displays very well on a root level page but I see no text in a subfolder page its blank. Any idea what's going wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

Check your paths. If they are relative, they may not be pointing to the proper directory when you are in a sub-directory.

Comment: I have tried absolute paths as well and have double checked the relative paths.

Comment: Post the relative code snippets to help debug. Even a live URL would be good.